# why can't I execute a simple powershell rasdial command in my runspace in a vb.net winforms app?

Tags: vb.net, powershell, pipeline, vpn, runspace

I've built an app that contains a PowerShell runspace.

It works perfectly for everything I've thrown at it.... until today.

One bit of functionality I've added detects when the user is trying to access corporate resources and will highlight if their VPN has become disconnected.

We use an always on VPN with certificate auth, so no username/password is required.

The runspace, and the app it is contained within run in the context of the user.

I've been able to demonstrate this by outputting the current environment user from within the runspace, which comes back as me (i.e. not system or administrator or anything silly).

I have a really simple bit of PowerShell that will attempt 4 times to reconnect the VPN before reporting back a failure, checking before each retry for a success.

This code works perfectly if I run ISE (standard, NOT elevated), but when I pass this code to be executed I get an error coming back from rasdial, which simply says 'the data is invalid'.

The PowerShell is simple enough...

```sh
$myvpn = Get-VpnConnection | Where-Object {$_.ServerAddress -eq "vpn.example.com"}
$VPNStatus = ( $myvpn ).ConnectionStatus
if ($VPNStatus -eq "Connected")
{
    $output= 0
}
else
{
    $attempt = 0
    DO
    {
        Write-output "not connected"
        rasdial $myvpn.name
        $check = (Get-VpnConnection | Where-Object {$_.ServerAddress -eq "vpn.example.com"}).ConnectionStatus
        start-sleep -Seconds 4
        $attempt ++
    } Until ($attempt -gt 3 -or $check -eq "Connected")
    if ($check -eq "Connected")
    {
        $output= 0
    }
    else
    {
        $output= 1
    }
}
```

I've got no idea why it won't work in the runspace, but will work in normal PowerShell with ease. My first suspicion was the context, but like I said I've disproven that theory.

I've googled the hell out of the error and can't seem to find any related results.

I've also tried to work around it, spawning an actual PowerShell session (ie not in a runspace) and passing in the command, but that also fails when spawned from my app.

Has anyone seen this before or similar behaviour when using runspaces/pipelines etc. within vb.net?

Are there any weird permissions pitfalls that I may have overlooked?

Edit: Expanded the powershell to be fully inclusive

Comment: Should we assume `$myvpn` was passed as parameter to the runspace scope?

Comment: I dont have the same issue in powershell alone, only when using the runspace in my vb.net app.   And indeed, $myvpn is further up the powershell.... I just didnt paste it all in for readability

Comment: @John I think that's important for the question. I'd include that point.

Comment: Edited accordingly :)

Answer (score 3):

So I've got to the bottom of this just now... Turns out the PS command will only work in an x64 shell, and my app's runspace was being spawned x86.

I changed the app to target x64 and it worked first time.

This post on [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29adce64-6c49-44c8-8c3f-000f84bfcaa9/rasdial-quotvpncoinnectionnamequot-command-gives-quotthe-data-is-invalidquot-error?forum=winservergen) was the breadcrumbs that got me over the finish line.